# JFXTabePane closing option is not working

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am trying to add close option in tabpane like a browser have it. Could you please tell me how to add closing feature in this tabpane? I tried this line but didn't solve my problem `tabPane.setTabClosingPolicy(TabClosingPolicy.ALL_TABS);`

I am using javafx jfoenix library for UI.

```
package tabsDemo;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.SingleSelectionModel;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane.TabClosingPolicy;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTabPane;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField;

public class TabsDemo extends Application {

    private String msg = "Tab 0";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Tabs");
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);

        JFXButton b1 = new JFXButton();
        b1.setId("back");
        b1.setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image("/tabsDemo/back.png")));
        b1.setMinWidth(20);
        b1.setMinHeight(20);
        b1.setMaxWidth(20);
        b1.setMaxHeight(20);

        JFXButton b2 = new JFXButton();
        b2.setId("farword");
        b2.setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image("/tabsDemo/forward.png")));
        b2.setMinWidth(20);
        b2.setMinHeight(20);
        b2.setMaxWidth(20);
        b2.setMaxHeight(20);

        JFXButton b3 = new JFXButton();
        b3.setId("refresh");
        b3.setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image("/tabsDemo/refresh.png")));
        b3.setMinWidth(20);
        b3.setMinHeight(20);
        b3.setMaxWidth(20);
        b3.setMaxHeight(20);

        JFXTextField t1 = new JFXTextField();
        t1.setMinWidth(100);
        // t1.setPrefWidth(900);
        // t1.setMaxWidth(1000);
        t1.setMinHeight(30);
        t1.setMaxHeight(30);

        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.setHgap(4);
        gridPane.add(b1, 0, 0);
        gridPane.add(b2, 1, 0);
        gridPane.add(b3, 2, 0);
        gridPane.add(t1, 3, 0);
        gridPane.setHgrow(t1, Priority.ALWAYS);

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setTop(gridPane);

        JFXTabPane tabPane = new JFXTabPane();
        Tab tab1 = new Tab();
        tab1.setText("Tab1");
        tab1.setContent(borderPane);

        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(new JFXButton("B1"), new JFXButton("B2"), new JFXButton("B3"), new JFXButton("B4"));
        Tab tab2 = new Tab();
        tab2.setText("Tab2");
        tab2.setContent(vbox);

        tabPane.getTabs().addAll(tab1, tab2);
        tabPane.setPrefSize(800, 600);

        // I add here the closing option for tab but it's not working
        tabPane.setTabClosingPolicy(TabClosingPolicy.ALL_TABS);

        SingleSelectionModel<Tab> selectionModel = tabPane.getSelectionModel();
        selectionModel.select(1);

        JFXButton button = new JFXButton("Add New Tab");

        button.setOnMouseClicked((o) -> {
            Tab temp = new Tab();
            int count = tabPane.getTabs().size();
            temp.setText(msg + count);
            temp.setContent(new Label("Tab 0" + count));
            tabPane.getTabs().add(temp);
        });

        borderPane.setRight(button);

        tabPane.setMaxSize(800, 600);

        /*
         * HBox hbox = new HBox(); hbox.getChildren().addAll(button, tabPane);
         * hbox.setSpacing(50); hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
         * hbox.setStyle("-fx-padding:20");
         */
        BorderPane rootBorderpane = new BorderPane();
        rootBorderpane.setCenter(tabPane);

        root.getChildren().addAll(rootBorderpane);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(TabsDemo.class.getResource("jfoenix-components.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        primaryStage.setTitle("JFX Tabs Demo");
    }

    private SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

    public String nextSessionId() {
        return new BigInteger(50, random).toString(16);
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I've added [commit](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/pull/241) to fix this issue, if you are still interested.

Answer (score 0):

Your `JFXTabPane` is a custom component from the JFoenix library, so there's no guarantee that all standard JavaFX settings, such as `TabClosingPolicy` in your case, are fully implemented.

I checked their GitHub repository and looks like there's an [unresolved issue](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/issues/75) regarding this missing feature. Someone forked the repository, apparently resolved the problem and submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/pull/192), but it's still has an open status. In other words, the changes are not included in the current build, so the bug still exists.

My suggestion is to stick with the standard JavaFX components, which should provide everything you need to create simple applications, including the closeable tabs, which are are working well as presented in the following example.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setTitle("JFX Tabs Demo");

    TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
    tabPane.setTabClosingPolicy(TabClosingPolicy.ALL_TABS);
    tabPane.getTabs().add(new Tab("Test"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(tabPane, 800, 600);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

[image: It works]

Comment: Thank you @Dth . I also look at the pull request and I also raise issue again in comments. I am just following now the TabPane as I am suffering a lot due to this (JFXTabPane) bug! but now I took your suggestion.